# Creating time series (NDVI) for each polygon contained in feature collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, polygon, google-earth-engine, time-series

I have an image collection of Landsat 5 and a feature collection of thousands polygons and points (in the example, I only have three). I would like to compute the NDVI (and NDWI) mean for each polygon over time like if I was using: **ui.Chart.image.series**;

If I am testing only one polygon with this code:

```
var p1= ee.Geometry.Point([-78.55995626672507,35.05443673532838])
var pol = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-78.57239414626946,35.01247143741747], 
[-78.57186843330254,35.012559309453266], 
[-78.57199717933526,35.01277020195395], 
[-78.57253362113823,35.01272626606113],
[-78.57239414626946,35.01247143741747]
]]);

var ens = [
ee.Feature(pol, {name: 'Thiessen'})
];

var col =  ee.FeatureCollection(ens)
print(col)

// NDVI: B4 and B3
var addNDVI = function(image) {
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

// Apply the cloud mask and NDVI function to Landsat 5 imagery and   print the chart
 var l5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1985,2007,'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
      .filterBounds(p1)
      .map(addNDVI) 

print(ui.Chart.image.series(l5.select('NDVI'), col, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
```

With this code I obtained [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/armIG.png). I would like to obtain the same type of figure with several polygon (one figure contains all the time series of the polygons).

I tried this code:

```
var p1= ee.Geometry.Point([-78.55995626672507,35.05443673532838])
var p2= ee.Geometry.Point([-78.5725093420931,35.05908805245044])
var pol = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-78.57239414626946,35.01247143741747], 
[-78.57186843330254,35.012559309453266], 
[-78.57199717933526,35.01277020195395], 
[-78.57253362113823,35.01272626606113],
[-78.57239414626946,35.01247143741747]
]]);

var ens = [
ee.Feature(p2, {name: 'Thiessen'}),
ee.Feature(pol, {name: 'Thiessen'})
];

var col =  ee.FeatureCollection(ens)
print(col)

// NDVI: B4 and B3
var addNDVI = function(image) {
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

// Apply the cloud mask and NDVI function to Landsat 5 imagery and    print the chart
var l5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1985,2007,'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
      .filterBounds(p1)
      .map(addNDVI) 

//Create a graph of the time-series.
var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: l5, 
regions: col, 
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 30,
})
print(graph)
```

This code provides [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At4NU.png)

The last code presents the graph as I would like. However, it does not compute what I want. For the polygon pol, I should have the same graphs with the two codes which is not the case. How could I have the same computation made with the code 1 but presented as the code 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first graph you have selected only the NDVI band using

```
l5.select('NDVI')
```

While in the second graph you do not do that, and then the band defaults to  the first band values. That's why the values differ. Try:

```
//Create a graph of the time-series.
var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: l5.select('NDVI'), 
regions: col, 
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 30,
})
print(graph)
```

or specifically select the band using:

```
//Create a graph of the time-series.
var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: l5, 
regions: col, 
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 30,
band: 'NDVI',
})
print(graph)
```